# how to display images in a list with fixed image size in python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

```
def getImgList(self, path, ext):
        imgList = [os.path.normcase(f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
        imgList = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in imgList if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == ext]
        self.images.extend(imgList)
        # image = Image.open(self.images)
        # photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        print(self.images)

def getImgOpen(self,seq):
    print('Opening %s' % seq)
    if seq=='ZERO':
        self.imgIndex = 0
    elif (seq == 'prev'):
        if (self.imgIndex == 0):
            self.imgIndex = len(self.images)-1
        else:
            self.imgIndex -= 1
    elif(seq == 'next'):
        if(self.imgIndex == len(self.images)-1):
            self.imgIndex = 0
        else:
            self.imgIndex += 1

    # self.masterImg = Image.open(self.images[self.imgIndex]) 
    # self.master.title(self.images[self.imgIndex])
    # self.masterImg.thumbnail((400,400))
    # self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.masterImg)
    # label = Label(image=self.img)
    # label.image = self.img # keep a reference!
    # label.pack()
    # label.place(x=400,y=100)
    # print(self.img)
    # self.lbl['image'] = self.img
    self.filename = self.images[self.imgIndex]
    self.original_image = cv2.imread(self.filename)
    # print(self.filename)
    self.edited_image = cv2.imread(self.filename)
    self.filtered_image = cv2.imread(self.filename)
    self.display_image(self.edited_image)
    return    
    d = Display();
    d.getImgOpen('next')
```

Comment: what is `Display()`? -- please review [ask] and [mre].

Comment: i want to display images in listbox .Display is for displaying image separately but i want in listbox

Comment: then this is a purely tkinter problem. you didn't tag that. I'll remove the OpenCV tag since reading the images is beside the point.